# passing the values dynamically (eg: innerHTML) to another element as a value

Tags: javascript, html, django, jinja2

I've a form with three fields, which are rendered via the ***jinja2*** template & the fields are part of a ***Django ModelForm***. The fields are: *CharField, FileField, and Textarea*.

And, I've also a *textarea* like `<div>` element which exactly works like **Stackoverflow's** editor, omitting some options like `<code>, <image> ...`

But, it's totally JavaScript based. Which when rendered on the page disabling that existing TextArea that was rendered from the ModelForm. As, I defined on the page...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtArea').TxtEdtr();
    });
</script>
```

I've mentioned both the element's IDs same, to always render the second textarea by overriding the first one. And, by hiding that element by - `display: none`.

And to pass the context of the 2nd created textarea to that modelform textarea, I've used:

```
$('.myeditor').keyup(function () {
    $('#txtArea').innerHTML = $('.myeditor').html();
});
```

By looking at the browser console I can see that **keyup** is working but, the  context or the 1st element isn't affected. And, as it's a required element I can't submit the form also.

[image: screenshot_of_editor]
For example, I want to pass that html context as a string to that ModelForm's textarea element before the form is submitted:

```
$('#txtEditor').innerHTML = $('.editor').html();
result to pass: "<span style=\"font-style: italic;\">hi there ...<br></span>"
```

which is shown to the console while I ran that code, but not able to pass.

The DOM structure:

```
<div class="form-group">

<!-- model form element -->
<label for="txtEditor">Body of article</label>
<textarea name="details" cols="40" rows="10"
    id="txtEditor" class="form-control" required="" style="display: none;">
</textarea>

<!-- after rendering -->
<div class="row-fluid main ted">
    <div id="menubar_txtEditor" class="row-fluid menu-bar">
        <!-- menubuttons are displayed here -->
        ...
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="editor" name="details" style="overflow: auto;" contenteditable="true">
        <!-- portions here dynamically added if textarea has
             any content inside -->
        <span style="font-style: italic;">hi there ...<br></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can prevent submit and then you can assign the  value from the text area to your model based text area

Which TxtEdtr (js plugin) you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
// add data to the editor
$('.editor').prepend($('#txtEditor').val());
// initialize TxtEdtr
window.quill = new Quill('.editor', {
  theme: 'snow'
});
// Update the model textarea value after submit
$('form').on('submit', function() {
  $('#txtEditor').val(quill.root.innerHTML);
});
```

Vist [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajanPaneru/phxye4sf/26/), for more.

> check network on jsfiddle, it's submitting the desired data.

Comment: Not worked for me... that **Quill editor** inherits it's own functionality which I've already implemented on my editor; yet, It's not submitting the form, as the flag required=true. my actual problem wasn't solved. anyway, thanks!

Comment: got some different solution.. so, need to require Quill. Thanks, for the idea!